# Jira connector eclipse conflicting dependency

Tags: eclipse, jira, mylyn-wikitext

I just tried to install the jira connector for mylyn, but eclipse reports the following problem

```
Problems occurred while performing installation: Operation details
Operation details
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Tasktop Dev Pro 4.8.1.v20161020-1951-RELEASE (com.tasktop.client.pro.feature.group 4.8.1.v20161020-1951-RELEASE)
Software currently installed: Mylyn WikiText 2.10.3.v20170505-2038 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group 2.10.3.v20170505-2038)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
Mylyn WikiText HTML 2.10.3.v20170505-2038 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.html.core 2.10.3.v20170505-2038)
Mylyn WikiText HTML 2.10.0.v20160630-1705 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.html.core 2.10.0.v20160630-1705)
Mylyn WikiText HTML 2.10.1.v20161129-1925 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.html.core 2.10.1.v20161129-1925)
Mylyn WikiText HTML 2.9.0.v20160513-1433 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.html.core 2.9.0.v20160513-1433)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Tasktop Artifacts Framework 12.0.1.v20161020-1920-RELEASE (com.tasktop.artifacts.feature.group 12.0.1.v20161020-1920-RELEASE)
To: org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.html.core [2.10.0.v20160630-1705]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Tasktop Dev Pro 4.8.1.v20161020-1951-RELEASE (com.tasktop.client.pro.feature.group 4.8.1.v20161020-1951-RELEASE)
To: com.tasktop.connector.zendesk.feature.group [4.8.1.v20161020-1930-RELEASE]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Tasktop Zendesk Connector 4.8.1.v20161020-1930-RELEASE (com.tasktop.connector.zendesk.feature.group 4.8.1.v20161020-1930-RELEASE)
To: com.tasktop.artifacts.feature.group [12.0.0,13.0.0)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Mylyn WikiText 2.10.3.v20170505-2038 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group 2.10.3.v20170505-2038)
To: org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.html.core [2.10.3.v20170505-2038]
```

I'm using eclipse neon and installed all updates that are currently available.

I don't know what eclipse wants to tell me with `Only one of the following can be installed at once:`. I thought that multiple versions can be installed in parallel in OSGI. Thus I don't know how to fix it.

Does anyone else have this problem or knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by first uninstalling `Mylyn WikiText HTML 2.10.3.v20170505-2038` and then installing the jira connector.

1. Help -> About -> Installation Details
2. Select `Mylyn WikiText HTML 2.10.3.v20170505-2038` and uninstall it. (Restart eclipse)
3. Open Task Repository View
4. Right click and select `Add Task Repository`
5. Use `Install More Connectors...`

Comment: Didn't work for me, still getting a conflict on commons net